# NbClust with large data sets. Sampling?

Tags: r, clustering, sampling

I have a data set which is 3 columns and about 50,000 rows. I am trying to do some cluster analysis and would like to speed it up. Most examples online use data sets like `iris` which are relatively tiny. Take the following code:

```
nb <- NbClust(d, distance = "euclidean", min.nc = 2, max.nc = 30, method = "complete", index ="all")
```

This has been running for 24 hours so far on a server with 32 cores and 100 gig of ram, although only one core will be being used.

There doesn't seem to be a way of doing any parallel processing unless I use a loop that tackles each index choice individually. That will speed up process considerably. However the real issue is size of the data. And 50,000 rows is hardly 'Big data'.

It seems using samples to speed up the process is a good idea. Like how `clara` is much faster than `pam`.

My question is, if I were to take samples and run `NbClust`, what size should the samples be and how many samples are sufficient?

I'd like the answer as a proportion of `n` - the number of total rows, such that this answer scales.

A final note would be that before doing any of this work, I would run `clustend` (or `hopkins`) to check the Hopkin's statistic to see if clustering even makes sense.

I have run:

`clustend <- get_clust_tendency(scale(d), 5000)`

But on large data sets this will also take a long time and I'm not sure if using samples like my above idea is wise or if you should really test the whole set to be sure. I'm also not sure if 5000 was the right number to choose, I'd seen examples where the number chosen was roughly 1/3 of the size of the data set, however these sets were under 300 rows and the choice hadn't been explained well.

Sample data:

```
 set.seed(123)
         d <- data.frame(x = unlist(lapply(1:500, function(i) rnorm(100, runif(1)*2^2))), 
               y = unlist(lapply(1:500, function(i) rnorm(100, runif(1)*2^2))),
               z = unlist(lapply(1:500, function(i) rnorm(100, runif(1)*2^2))))
```

UPDATE:

Here are the results of nb clust, which is why I don't want to use less tests and also may be evidence why a sample may misrepresent the data

```
* Among all indices:
* 6 proposed 2 as the best number of clusters
* 5 proposed 3 as the best number of clusters
* 2 proposed 5 as the best number of clusters
* 4 proposed 8 as the best number of clusters
* 2 proposed 10 as the best number of clusters
* 1 proposed 13 as the best number of clusters
* 1 proposed 23 as the best number of clusters
* 1 proposed 24 as the best number of clusters
* 1 proposed 27 as the best number of clusters
```

Comment: I'd probably take sample sizes of 1000 and maybe 10 samples and see if all the results tell the same story. If so good, if not run more samples. But wondering if there are more specific rules, especially as data sets continue to increase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many clustering algorithms depend on some distance measure between the 
points. With 50,000 points, the distance matrix for your data will be 
too big for many computing environments. It may be that the resultant 
matrix could fit into your 100 Gigabytes of RAM, but it does not surprise 
me that computing on that scale take a *long* time.

Of course, sampling is a natural response to that problem. I do not have 
a direct answer for you about sample size or number of samples, but I do 
have a suggestion about what you should consider in making those choices. 
I am afraid it is a rather unsatisfying suggestion:  it depends on your 
data and what you want to do with it.

First imagine that your 50,000 data points consists of two natural clusters 
that are fairly well separated from each other and approximately equal in size.
Each of the clusters contain about 25,000 points and suppose further that 
there is a small amount of noise in your data so that there are 500 (1%)
noise points that do not cluster well with anything. Your comment made the 
(reasonable) proposal of taking 10 samples of size 1000. This procedure 
should do a good job of revealing the underlying structure of data like this
and help you to make good decisions about how to handle the full data set.

However, suppose instead that your data has those same two well separated 
clusters of equal size, 400 noise points and also has another group of about 
100 points that are tightly clustered and well separated from the two main
clusters.  Your samples of size 1000 would mostly contain about 2
points from this smaller cluster and 8 of the noise points. It would be very 
easy to simply interpret the points from the small cluster as part of the 
noise, completely missing the existence of the smaller cluster.

[image: Sampled data]

Seeing these two possibilities, it seems important to ask "Should you care?".
That is why it matters what you want to do with the clustering. Suppose you 
were developing target marketing campaign for a mass-market product with broad 
appeal.  Ignoring the small cluster (0.2% of the market) might be just fine. 
But if you were trying to isolate the market for a product that only appeals 
to a small, select group, ignoring that group could be a disaster. Is a coarse
description of your data sufficient for your purposes or do you need to know 
about smaller sub-populations?  Your sample size together with the size of
any sub-populations will determine whether they are apparent in your samples.

Comment: 'Many'. I'd go as far as saying that most don't require a distance matrix. K-means? GMM? DBSCAN? OPTICS? none of them requires a distance matrix, and they can be used on much larger data than 50k.

Comment: Feels dirty to try and mimic the distribution naively by picking a sample by eye that looks to share the same characteristics. Perhaps just choosing ten samples like I thought, but inspecting that those ten have points from all areas that may need to be considered.

As for kmeans etc, the point was to try and use many different methods, hence dbclust. The elbow method is too ambiguous for my data for example.